# How to draw multi-textured cube using WebGL

Tags: textures, webgl

I have tried to draw a multi-textured cube using WebGL.

Now this code is running normally with no error, but the cube is drawn with all 6 faces having the same texture (last texture). I just want to draw a cube multi-textured with 6 different faces.

Please point me where the code is wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="sylvester.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="glUtils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
        varying float vFace;

        uniform sampler2D front;
        uniform sampler2D back;
        uniform sampler2D top;
        uniform sampler2D bottom;
        uniform sampler2D right;
        uniform sampler2D left;

        void main(void) {
            if (vFace < 0.1)
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(front, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            else if (vFace < 1.1)
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(back, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            else if (vFace < 2.1)
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(top, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            else if (vFace < 3.1)
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(bottom, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            else if (vFace < 4.1)
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(right, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            else
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(left, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        }
    </script>
    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
        attribute float aFace;

        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

        varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
        varying float vFace;

        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
            vFace = aFace;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
    <canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480">
        Your browser doesn't appear to support the HTML5 <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code> element.
    </canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var cubeVerticesBuffer;
var cubeVerticesTextureCoordBuffer;
var textureLookupBuffer;
var cubeVerticesIndexBuffer;
var cubeRotation = 0.0;
var lastCubeUpdateTime = 0;

var cubeImage;
var cubeTexture;

var mvMatrix;
var shaderProgram;
var vertexPositionAttribute;
var textureCoordAttribute;
var textureLookUpAttribute;
var perspectiveMatrix;

//
// start
//
// Called when the canvas is created to get the ball rolling.
//
function start() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
    // Initialize the GL context
    initWebGL(canvas);

    // Only continue if WebGL is available and working
    if (gl) {
        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Clear to black, fully opaque
        gl.clearDepth(1.0);                 // Clear everything
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);           // Enable depth testing
        gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);            // Near things obscure far things

        // Initialize the shaders; this is where all the lighting for the
        // vertices and so forth is established.
        initShaders();

        // Here's where we call the routine that builds all the objects
        // we'll be drawing.
        initBuffers();

        // Next, load and set up the textures we'll be using.
        initTextures();

        // Set up to draw the scene periodically.
        setInterval(drawScene, 15);
    }
}

//
// initWebGL
//
// Initialize WebGL, returning the GL context or null if
// WebGL isn't available or could not be initialized.
//
function initWebGL() {
    gl = null;

    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    }
    catch(e) {
    }

    // If we don't have a GL context, give up now
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.");
    }
}

//
// initShaders
//
// Initialize the shaders, so WebGL knows how to light our scene.
//
function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    // Create the shader program
    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // If creating the shader program failed, alert
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Unable to initialize the shader program: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shader));
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);

    textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordAttribute);

    textureLookUpAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aFace");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(textureLookUpAttribute);
}

//
// getShader
//
// Loads a shader program by scouring the current document,
// looking for a script with the specified ID.
//
function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

    // Didn't find an element with the specified ID; abort.
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    // Walk through the source element's children, building the
    // shader source string.
    var theSource = "";
    var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

    while(currentChild) {
        if (currentChild.nodeType == 3) {
            theSource += currentChild.textContent;
        }

        currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
    }

    // Now figure out what type of shader script we have,
    // based on its MIME type.
    var shader;

    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;  // Unknown shader type
    }

    // Send the source to the shader object
    gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);

    // Compile the shader program
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    // See if it compiled successfully
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}

//
// initBuffers
//
// Initialize the buffers we'll need. For this demo, we just have
// one object -- a simple two-dimensional cube.
//
function initBuffers() {

    // Create a buffer for the cube's vertices.
    cubeVerticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    // Now create an array of vertices for the cube.
    var vertices = [
        // Front face
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

        // Back face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

        // Top face
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

        // Bottom face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

        // Right face
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

        // Left face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
    ];

    // Select the cubeVerticesBuffer as the one to apply vertex
    // operations to from here out.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesBuffer);

    // Now pass the list of vertices into WebGL to build the shape. We
    // do this by creating a Float32Array from the JavaScript array,
    // then use it to fill the current vertex buffer.
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var textureCoordinates = [
        // Front
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        // Back
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        // Top
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        // Bottom
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        // Right
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        // Left
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0
    ];

    // Map the texture onto the cube's faces.
    cubeVerticesTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesTextureCoordBuffer);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoordinates), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    //
    var lookUpArray = [
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,      //Front face
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,      //Back face
        2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0,      //Top face
        3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0,      //Bottom face
        4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0,      //Right face
        5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0      //Left face
    ];

    textureLookupBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureLookupBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(lookUpArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // This array defines each face as two triangles, using the
    // indices into the vertex array to specify each triangle's
    // position.
    var cubeVertexIndices = [
        0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3,    // front
        4,  5,  6,      4,  6,  7,    // back
        8,  9,  10,     8,  10, 11,   // top
        12, 13, 14,     12, 14, 15,   // bottom
        16, 17, 18,     16, 18, 19,   // right
        20, 21, 22,     20, 22, 23    // left
    ];
    // Build the element array buffer; this specifies the indices
    // into the vertex array for each face's vertices.
    cubeVerticesIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesIndexBuffer);
    // Now send the element array to GL
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

//
// initTextures
//
// Initialize the textures we'll be using, then initiate a load of
// the texture images. The handleTextureLoaded() callback will finish
// the job; it gets called each time a texture finishes loading.
//
function initTextures() {
    cubeTexture = [];
    cubeImage = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        var texture = gl.createTexture();
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() { handleTextureLoaded(image, texture); }
        image.src = "option_110" + (i+1) + ".jpg";
        cubeImage.push(image);
        console.log(cubeImage[i].src);
    }

}

function handleTextureLoaded(image, texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    /*gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);*/
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);     gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
    //gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    cubeTexture.push(texture);
}

//
// drawScene
//
// Draw the scene.
//
function drawScene() {
    // Clear the canvas before we start drawing on it.
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Establish the perspective with which we want to view the
    // scene. Our field of view is 45 degrees, with a width/height
    // ratio of 640:480, and we only want to see objects between 0.1 units
    // and 100 units away from the camera.
    perspectiveMatrix = makePerspective(100, 640.0/480.0, 0.1, 100.0);
    //perspectiveMatrix = makeOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, 0.1, 100);

    // Set the drawing position to the "identity" point, which is
    // the center of the scene.
    loadIdentity();

    // Now move the drawing position a bit to where we want to start
    // drawing the cube.
    mvTranslate([-0.0, 0.0, -6.0]);

    // Save the current matrix, then rotate before we draw.
    mvPushMatrix();
    mvRotate(cubeRotation, [1, 0, 1]);

    // Draw the cube by binding the array buffer to the cube's vertices
    // array, setting attributes, and pushing it to GL.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Set the texture coordinates attribute for the vertices.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesTextureCoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureCoordAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    //
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureLookupBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureLookUpAttribute, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Specify the texture to map onto the faces.
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture[0]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "front"), 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture[1]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "back"), 1);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture[2]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "top"), 2);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE3);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture[3]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "bottom"), 3);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE4);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture[4]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "right"), 4);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE5);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture[5]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "left"), 5);

    // Draw the cube.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesIndexBuffer);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // Restore the original matrix
    mvPopMatrix();

    // Update the rotation for the next draw, if it's time to do so.
    var currentTime = (new Date).getTime();
    if (lastCubeUpdateTime) {
        var delta = currentTime - lastCubeUpdateTime;

        cubeRotation += (30 * delta) / 1000.0;
    }

    lastCubeUpdateTime = currentTime;
}



//
// Matrix utility functions
//

function loadIdentity() {
    mvMatrix = Matrix.I(4);
}

function multMatrix(m) {
    mvMatrix = mvMatrix.x(m);
}

function mvTranslate(v) {
    multMatrix(Matrix.Translation($V([v[0], v[1], v[2]])).ensure4x4());
}

function setMatrixUniforms() {
    var pUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pUniform, false, new Float32Array(perspectiveMatrix.flatten()));

    var mvUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mvUniform, false, new Float32Array(mvMatrix.flatten()));
}

var mvMatrixStack = [];

function mvPushMatrix(m) {
    if (m) {
        mvMatrixStack.push(m.dup());
        mvMatrix = m.dup();
    } else {
        mvMatrixStack.push(mvMatrix.dup());
    }
}

function mvPopMatrix() {
    if (!mvMatrixStack.length) {
        throw("Can't pop from an empty matrix stack.");
    }

    mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
    return mvMatrix;
}

function mvRotate(angle, v) {
    var inRadians = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var m = Matrix.Rotation(inRadians, $V([v[0], v[1], v[2]])).ensure4x4();
    multMatrix(m);
}
```

Comment: Do the following: 

1) check if `vFace` is correct. Add `'gl_FragColor = vec4(vFace/5.0);` at end and see if you get a different shade for each face.

2) check if the textures are loaded correctly. Use `'gl_FragColor = texture2D(left/up/right/..., vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t))'` instead  and see if you see a different texture each time.

Comment: @WaclawJasper I got self answer. Anyway, thank you for comment. You're right. I modified to change cubeTexture array to individual variable for each texture and then, solve the problem

Comment: Just in case - this is not the recommended way to put a different texture on each side of a cube. Of course you're free to do whatever you want but for example if you wanted to put a different face on each side of a dodecahedron (20 sides) you'd need 20 texture units which is more than many GPUs have. - the more common thing to do is use a texture atlas. Put all 6 images in 1 texture, use texture coordinates to select them. If you want to do it at runtime use the 2d canvas api and copy the 6 images you downloaded into a 2d canvas then upload that as your texture.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37134634/128511 (I marked this as a dup. The question is a dup, the details might not be, but I'm guessing most people searching for an answer based on the question will want the dupped answer)